# In which form Memgraph supports graph projection?

Tags: memgraphdb

As a part of the project, I need to project some subgraphs from the main graph. However, I'm unclear about the mechanisms Memgraph provides to support graph projection. I need to isolate a certain part of the graph. I've taken a look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864406/does-memgraph-support-subgraphs) and I've read the blog post at https://memgraph.com/blog/how-we-designed-and-implemented-graph-projection-feature but I didn't find any info on isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memgraph supports graph projection using the `project()` function (as explained in blog post that you have linked). You can use it to construct a subgraph out of the generated paths:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r]->(m)  
WITH project(p) AS subgraph  
RETURN subgraph;
```

To isolate a certain part of the graph, you can add constraints to labels, edge types, or properties:

```
MATCH p=(n:SpecificLabel)-[r:REL_TYPE]->(m:SpecificLabel)  
WITH project(p) AS subgraph  
RETURN subgraph;
```

This query will return a subgraph of `SpecificLabel` nodes connected with the relationships of type `REL_TYPE`.